# Anaconda: conda install langid for Win x64

Tags: installation, anaconda, tar, conda

it seems Anaconda does not include the langid add-on package for Win x64.
Tried the following in the command prompt:

```
conda install langid ---> No packages found in current win-64 channels matching langid

anaconda search -t conda langid --> reveals 3 packages but only for linux-64 and osx-64 but not for Win 64
```

I downloaded the tar.gz package manually and placed it into /Anaconda/pkgs

```
 conda install path/filename.tar.gz
```

does not work anyway, probably because of the .gz source file type....

Thus my question: How can I work around this to use langid in spyder/anaconda on Win64? (I double checked pip install langid, it works perfectly fine in IDLE...)

Comment: Seriously no one? # push please

Comment: Still no response in here so far? ## PUSH PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

Just install via pip: `python -m pip install langid`.